# Conversion of a Java Web Start app to an Applet

Tags: java, applet

I'm trying to figure out how difficult it would be to convert a Java Web Start app to an applet.  Theoretically, if the application didn't do anything such as write to the file system...basically if all of it's actions should be safe within the Applet sandbox, how tricky would it be?  Is it a matter of wrapping the main app inside of an applet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be quite straight forward.  Simply create an applet class.  From within the applet class you can instantiate whatever class JWS would normally start.

You then need to convert the JWS xml file to an applet tag and put it on a web page.

Comment: Why on earth would anyone still want to use an applet?
Why not look into using some kind of ajax framework like GWT or have a look at Java Fx.

Comment: Applet's continue to look uglier as they haven't kept pace with native look and feels.  However, an applet or JWS can be run just by going to a web page - which GWT/RCP can't.  JavaFX is immature, and would require rewriting the apps entire GUI.